# Tkinter метод .after()

Tags: python, tkinter, while

пытался сделать такую вещь чтобы каждую секунду прибавлялось в переменную по +1 пока CheckButton включен, переменную я установил, но не пойму как каждую секунду прибавлять по +1.

```
def AutoEarner(): #Проблема в этой функции
    if Button_AutoEarner_State.get() == 1:
        while Button_AutoEarner_State.get() == 1:
            window.after(1000, AddBalance)

def AddBalance():
    global balance
    balance =+ 1
    lbl_balance.configure(text="Баланс: {0}".format(balance))


Button_AutoEarner_State = IntVar()
Button_AutoEarner_State.set(0)
Button_AutoEarner = Checkbutton(window, text='Автозаработок', font=("Arial Bold", 15), command=AutoEarner, variable=Button_AutoEarner_State)  
Button_AutoEarner.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`AutoEarner` полностью заменяет цикл, в нем не нужен `while`, и он должен самого себя ставить на выполнение через 1000 миллисекунд (т.е. должно быть `window.after(1000, AutoEarner)` вместо `window.after(1000, AddBalance)`).

Далее, как я понял вашу идею, этот "цикл" должен выполняться все время работы программы, поэтому нужно вручную его вызвать, а не добавлять в `command` переключателя, только в зависимости от состояния переключателя - вызывать или не вызывать функцию `AddBalance`.

Код получается примерно такой:

```
def AutoEarner():
    if Button_AutoEarner_State.get() == 1:
        AddBalance()

    window.after(1000, AutoEarner)


def AddBalance():
    global balance
    balance =+ 1
    lbl_balance.configure(text="Баланс: {0}".format(balance))


Button_AutoEarner_State = IntVar()
Button_AutoEarner_State.set(0)
Button_AutoEarner = Checkbutton(window, text='Автозаработок', font=("Arial Bold", 15), variable=Button_AutoEarner_State)  
Button_AutoEarner.grid(column=0, row=0)

AutoEarner()
```